# JWT decoding say invalid signature even on providing correct "signing" key

Tags: json, jwt, tokenize, jjwt

JWT tokenization is driving me crazy or I am using it wrong.

To test out and start with "jjwt", i am creating a simple jwt token, below is the code.

```
static String createSimpleJWT() {
        String id, issuer, subject;
        id="id";
        issuer="issuer";
        subject="subject";

        //Let's set the JWT Claims
        JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId(id)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "signingKey");  //plz note signing key on this line
        return builder.compact();
}
```

The jwt token is

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJpZCIsInN1YiI6InN1YmplY3QiLCJpc3MiOiJpc3N1ZXIifQ._7QGamE-HvREDMJIgbfKEIRv76ZaxwIx2t3RaViSYzth4

As intended, on subsequent executions also I get the same JWT.

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJpZCIsInN1YiI6InN1YmplY3QiLCJpc3MiOiJpc3N1ZXIifQ._7QGE-HvREDMJIgbfKEIRv76ZaxwIx2t3RaViSYzth4

I am decoding it using jwt.io to test - 
but am suprised to see that the jwt token is flaged with Invalid Signature inspite of providing the correct signing key in the  decode section.

Here is jwt.io screenshot - [jwt.io-invalidsignature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6CsJ.jpg)

Any pointers... where it's getting messed.

This post is different from what's asked earlier where the users forgot or were not aware about providing signing key to jwt.io 
[PHP JWT Token Invalid Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658943/php-jwt-token-invalid-signature)
[JWT Token Invalid Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570389/jwt-token-invalid-signature)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269014/6371459.

> It is due to `.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secret")`. It is implemented by DefaultJwtBuilder class
>
> ```
> public JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm alg, String base64EncodedSecretKey)
> ```
>
> This method assumes that you are providing a key in base64 and **`secret` is not base64**. When the method decodes from `base64` to `byte[]` the java converter used by *jjwt* provides a representation of the string `secr` which is different to the JavaScript decoder used at **jwt.io**

`JWTBuilder.signWith` requires a base64 encoded key, but you are providing a plain text, so:

- Insert "signingK" and check "secret base64 encoded" in jwt.io
- Provide a base64 encoded password

--

```
String signingKeyB64= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("signingKey".getBytes("utf-8"));
JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId(id)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, signingKeyB64);
```

---

I recommend to generate a random password instead of using a fixed string

```
Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();
String signingKeyB64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded());
```

Comment: If we generate a random password while generating the token, how will we get the same password when calling the JWT parse() setSigningKey () while decoding the JWT incoming with request?

Comment: @james you have to store the generated key somewhere to be able to use it for verification. It is not necessary to generate a key for each token, you can reuse it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same issue with this JWT lib so I changed it to another one. Don't know why this happens. My Application is used to authenticate against a third party system.

Try this Lib an check it again, perhaps this helps you:

https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

Comment: was using latest 0.9.0 version earlier.. now tried with  6, 7 and 8 also... no luck.

Comment: another strange thing, even on providing wrong secret in the decoder java code, there is no throwing of exception and the decode is happening normally.